# SoapUI JMS Connections

Tags: soapui, ibm-mq

I am using SoapUI to do performance testing of some services over JMS using WebSphere MQ as the JMS Provider. SoapUI uses HermesJMS to provide the JMS Connection details for the JMS Endpoint.

I've noticed that when I call a request from SoapUI the JMS Connection is never closed. This results in hundreds of **SYSTEM.DEF.SVRCONN** channel connections.

It seems to be specific to SoapUI as HermeJMS doesn't exhibit this behaviour.

Has anyone else seen this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

we made some changes in the code that hopefully help you with this problem.

Check out our nightly build tomorrow  ( http://www.eviware.com/nightly-builds/ ) and let us know does it helps.

best regards
nebojsa
eviware.com